# highstocks hozontal line won't draw

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I'm trying to get my highcharts plot to draw the recent minima and maxima.

I already figured the correct JSON sub-object is "plotLines", however my script just refuses to draw them without any error. Maybe someone of you can spot my error. The corresponding (and probably wrong, but that doesn't really matter for this example) values are listed to the left

[image: my plot]

thanks!

Comment: What errors does it give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With you current values, the lines will never plot.

Your axis min is sitting at 500, and you are plotting lines at 498.
The axis will not expand to show plotLines or plotBands - it will only expand to show data (or based on minPadding/maxPAdding, etc).

You will need to check that your lines are within your axis min/max in order to display them.

You can do that by using the getExtremes() method, and if needed, the setExtremes() method:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes

*Edit to incorporate comments:*

If the line is the same value as a grid line, you will need to set a zIndex on either the plotLine or the gridLines - by default the gridLines are above the plotLines

Comment: If the line is the same value as a grid line, you will need to set a zIndex on either the plotLine or the gridLines - by default the gridLines are above the plotLines

Comment: Oh well, that was obscure. Thanks a lot!